# How to use the string returned by $() to be used as more than one argument in another command?

Tags: bash, string, command-substitution

**My use case:**

I need to remove all dev packages listed in `composer.json` file. Suppose I have two packages: `projectx/package-nice` and `projecty/package-good`. To remove them I need to run:

```
$ composer remove --dev projectx/package-nice projecty/package-good
```

So I build this command to extract the package list:

```
echo $(composer show -s | grep -E "^[a-z]+/[0-9a-z_-]+" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs)
```

This return the list of packages, exacly like this: `projectx/package-nice projecty/package-good`

So I tried to run the command below, but didn't work because bash is interpreting the return as a single string enclosed by quotes:

```
$ composer remove --dev $(composer show -s | grep -E "^[a-z]+/[0-9a-z_-]+" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs)
```

It's the same as:

```
$ composer remove --dev "projectx/package-nice projecty/package-good"
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

*edit:*

Note that the problem is not about the parsing. The `$()` is returning the expected values separated by spaces. The issue is about WHY bash is interpreting this return as a unique value.

As @MarcusMüller noted, this problem shouldn't be happening. Inside `/etc` I ran:

```
$ ls $(ls | head -n 2)
```

and the executed command was `ls file1 file2` and not `ls "file1 file2"`, so I don't understand why this is happening. Maybe it's because composer is just a script that is run by php, and this is interfering with something?

Thank you.

Comment: *bash interprets the return as a single string enclosed by quotes* usually it doesn't, and that becomes a problem, often. So, hm.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "usually it doesn't". 
Well, I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON document? I expect it to be fairly easy to parse it with e.g. `jq` and extract the package names into an array.

Comment: @Kusalananda The problem isn't about the json parsing, this is just an example. The problem is about executing a command that receives n parameters separated by spaces  returned by the $()

Comment: @Lawrence If you parse the JSON appropriately, you could output the package names in a form that would make it easy to handle the data in the shell, such as shell-quoted strings. This is something that `jq` can do for you.  Also note that generally, JSON strings are _encoded_ and needs to be decoded.

Comment: As @MarcusMüller noted, this problem shouldn't be happening. Inside `/etc` I tried to run: `ls $(ls | head -n 2)` and the executed command was `ls file1 file2` and not `ls "file1 file2"`, so I don't understand why this is happening. Maybe it's because `composer` is a script that is run by php, and this is interfering with some bash magic?

Comment: 1. This shell behavior depends on the value of the built-in variable IFS. If that is somehow set to the empty string, or it doesn't contain all of tab, newline, and space, the shell will not split strings into words in many situations, including this one. 2. What is the purpose of xargs here? I think you're mixing up two different paradigms of reusing the output of commands. Direct interpolation as arguments of another command is one paradigm, piping into xargs another, different paradigm.

Comment: @q.undertow Your comment led me to find a solution, thank you. Please post as an answer so I can mark as correct.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit adding a solution in the question itself.  If you have a solution, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer  Note that the fact that a solution was hinted at by someone else in a comment does not stop you from using that hint to write your own proper answer.

Comment: I think that Stephane's answer is (as usual for him) not just correct, but comprehensive to the point of exhaustion :-) I think you should mark it.

Answer (score 2):

```
composer remove --dev $(composer show -s | grep -E "^[a-z]+/[0-9a-z_-]+" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs)
```

is not the same as:

```
composer remove --dev "projectx/package-nice projecty/package-good"
```

The `$(cmd)` part, because it is not quoted and in list context (in arguments to a simple command here) is subject to split+glob.

Unless you've modified it, `$IFS` (which is used for the *split* part) happens to contain the space character, so if `cmd` outputs `projectx/package-nice projecty/package-good\n`, that will be split into `projectx/package-nice` and `projecty/package-good` and passed as separate arguments to `composer`.

By the way, newline is also in the default value of `$IFS`, so your `xargs` (which I suppose is there to convert the newlines to spaces¹) is rather pointless.

Rather than using split+glob, if using the `bash` shell, using `readarray` to read the lines of some file into individual elements of an array would make more sense:

```
readarray -t packages < <(
  composer show -s | grep -Po '^\p{Ll}+/[\p{Ll}\d_-]\H*'
)
(( ${#packages[@]} == 0 )) ||
  composer remove --dev "${packages[@]}"
```

Using split+glob is also an option, but as always, when using it it's best to tune it for your exact need:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split on newline only
set -o noglob # disable the glob part which we don't want
packages=( $(cmd...) ) # split+glob, result assigned to an array
```

In your case, the output of `cmd` should not contain space nor tab characters, the other two characters that are in the default value of `$IFS` in `bash`, so you could leave `$IFS` as is.

But it might contain globs. For instance, if `composer show -s` output `etc/p* blah blah` for instance, your pipeline would output `etc/p*`, and  if run from within `/`, without the `set -o noglob`, that `etc/p*` would be expanded to `etc/pam.conf`, `etc/passwd`, `etc/profile`...

To prevent split+glob, for the output of `cmd` (minus the trailing newlines that are stripped by command-substitution) to be passed as one and only one argument to the command, you use double quote:

```
composer remove --dev "$(cmd)"
```

(which only makes sense if `cmd` outputs only one package).

On Linux, you can see what arguments are being passed to a command using

```
strace -s999999 -qqfe execve the-command and its args
```

(or run that `strace` command on your shell to trace all the `execve()` system calls that it or any of the processes it spawns make)

For instance:

split+glob with the default value of IFS:

```
bash-5.0$ strace -s999999 -qqfe execve true $(echo foo; echo foo bar)
execve("/usr/bin/true", ["true", "foo", "foo", "bar"], 0x7ffe1374cc50 /* 66 vars */) = 0
```

Splitting on newline only:

```
bash-5.0$ (IFS=$'\n'; strace -s999999 -qqfe execve true $(echo foo; echo; echo foo bar))
execve("/usr/bin/true", ["true", "foo", "foo bar"], 0x7ffd16c547f8 /* 66 vars */) = 0
```

(note that the empty line is removed).

Effect of the glob part:

```
bash-5.0$ (strace -s999999 -qqfe execve true $(echo 'etc/p*'))
execve("/usr/bin/true", ["true", "etc/pam.conf", "etc/pam.d", "etc/papersize", "etc/parallel", "etc/passwd", "etc/passwd-", "etc/pcmcia", "etc/perl", "etc/php", "etc/pki", "etc/pm", "etc/pnm2ppa.conf", "etc/polkit-1", "etc/popularity-contest.conf", "etc/ppp", "etc/printcap", "etc/profile", "etc/profile.d", "etc/protocols", "etc/pulse", "etc/python2.7", "etc/python3", "etc/python3.8"], 0x7ffdc911f8a0 /* 66 vars */) = 0
```

Fixed with `set -o noglob`:

```
bash-5.0$ (set -o noglob; strace -s999999 -qqfe execve true $(echo 'etc/p*'))
execve("/usr/bin/true", ["true", "etc/p*"], 0x7ffe9c278a50 /* 66 vars */) = 0
```

Split+glob disabled by quoting:

```
bash-5.0$ (IFS=$'\n'; strace -s999999 -qqfe execve true "$(echo foo; echo; echo foo bar; echo 'etc/p*')")
execve("/usr/bin/true", ["true", "foo\n\nfoo bar\netc/p*"], 0x7ffcf0e70d20 /* 66 vars */) = 0
```

In `zsh`, only the IFS-splitting part is done upon unquoted command substitution, not the glob part (ksh also does brace expansion in addition to split+glob). In `zsh`, you can also apply an explicit splitting on top of command substitution using the `s`, `f`, `0` parameter expansion flags. For instance `${(f)"$(cmd)"}` splits the output of `cmd` on newlines, so here, you'd do:

```
packages=( ${(f)"$(composer show -s | grep -Po '^\p{Ll}+/[\p{Ll}\d_-]\H*')"} )
(( $#packages == 0 )) || composer remove --dev $packages
```

Without having to modify `$IFS` nor disable globbing globally.

---

<sup>¹ the wrong way to do it as there are many ways that could fail for arbitrary input and is quite inefficient.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You have the solution on hand. Your `echo` command returns 2 strings separated by a space. Enclose that one in a `$()` command substitution (yes, they can be nested) and you get what you need:

```
composer remove --dev $(echo $(composer show -s | grep -E "^[a-z]+/[0-9a-z_-]+" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs))
```

Comment: I don't how this would help. Or do pretty much anything, really. With the default `IFS`, the output from the inner command substitution would be split on spaces, and passed to `echo` as distinct words, and then `echo` would join them with single spaces, print them, and then that (the output from the outer command substitution) would again be split. Just one command substitution would do the same.

Comment: @ilkkachu The problem at hand is said to be a case where the result of the innermost command substitution is NOT split on spaces. But the second one, with the echo, does the splitting just fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter. An unquoted command substitution would split (or not) the same as an unquoted command substitution. That is, it'd split on whitespace if `IFS` is unset, or it would not if `IFS` is set to the empty string (or it would split on whatever `IFS` is set to, if it's set to something different). Perhaps their issue is that `IFS` is modified from the default, and there's no splitting, but that would mean there wouldn't be any splitting on the _other_ command substitution either. So, I don't see any scenario where this would help.